# case sensitive PHP

Tags: php

Quero que uma variavel que é passado por POST possa ser case-insensitive, ou seja se por exemplo a variavel for "Teste", ser igual a "teste". Sei que existe em PHP o strcasecmp, que faz isso. O problema é que faço uma pesquisa na tabela (base de dados em SQLite) desse valor passado por POST. Na tabela existe por exemplo um campo com este valor Teste, e se é passado teste, saber que se trata desse campo.
aqui fica a minha consulta a tabela:

```
$requete="SELECT * FROM contact WHERE nom='$search'";
```

e o valor

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) 
{
    $search= htmlentities($_POST['search']);
}
```

Comment: É importante que a acentuação seja ignorada?

Comment: no PHP ou no SQLite?

Comment: resolvi utilizando ucwords($search);

Answer (score 6):

### Se o problema for na *query*:

```
$requete = "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE LOWER( nom ) = LOWER( '$search' )";
```

ou então:

```
$search = mb_strtolower( $search );
$requete = "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE LOWER( nom ) = '$search'";
```

Ou função equivalente, pois não foi especificado o SGBD na questão. Lembrando que neste caso é fundamental usar a *collation* correta para a língua em uso nas linguagens envolvidas.

O **[*SQL Injection*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=SQL+Injection+is%3Aquestion)** vem de brinde em todos estes códigos. Dê uma pesquisada **[aqui no SOpt mesmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=SQL+Injection+is%3Aquestion)**, tem uma série de respostas explicando como resolver. Independente da dúvida original da questão, seu código cedo ou tarde vai te dar problema sério com isso

### Se o problema for no nome dos parâmetros:

<sub>Normalmente isso não deveria ser necessário, e só deve ser usado se existir uma razão consciente para tal. Em geral, o melhor é usar coerência ao dar nome em todas as coisas em PHP (e qualquer outra linguagem). Relendo a situação atual da pergunta, creio que a 1a parte da resposta seja a solução, e não esta.</sub>

Com esta linha normalizamos o *case* dos parâmetros:

```
$_POST_MIN = array_change_key_case( $_POST, CASE_LOWER );
```

E depois usar desta forma, sempre em minúsculas:

```
if (isset($_POST_MIN['search'])) 
{
    $search= htmlentities($_POST_MIN['search']);
}
```

Comment: +1 O problema não é nem no PHP, é na collation da base.